# Как менять регистр английских букв в Visual Studio с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-studio, notepad++

Рефакторю большой проект с помощью Visual Studio Find and Replace и не получается менять регистр с помощью регулярных выражений. Интересны только большие английские буквы. Нужно заменить UPPERCASE на TitleCase внутри определённых символов. Например, нужно заменить `<td>USER NAME</td>` на `<td>User Name</td>`.

Comment: Не стоит и пытаться. Используйте Notepad++. `(?:\G(?!^)|<td>)\s*[^<\s]\K[^<\s]*` -> `\L$&`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew для сотен файлов?

Comment: Да, ничего особенного, можно и тысяч.

Comment: Так как, пробовали? Функция "Найти в фалах" - "Заменить в файлах".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Нет, решил другими (обходными) способами решать задачу. Каждый файл переносить в Notepad++ в данном случае только усложнит всё.

Comment: Зачем переносить? См. http://imgur.com/a/MjJqa. Можете описать свои обходные пути в ответе.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ух ты, спасибо! Классное решение. Не знал, что так можно. Если хотите, напишите это как ответ, я его прийму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю решение, основанное на возможностях Notepad++. В окне "Найти в файлах" выберите необходимый путь к папке с файлами, задайте маску и используйте следующие значения для двух полей:

*Найти*:            `(?:\G(?!^)|<td>)\s*[^<\s]\K[^<\s]*`
*Заменить на*: `\L$&`

**Подробности**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<td>)` - найти `<td>`, а все последующие совпадения должны начинаться с того места, где закончилось предыдущее
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `[^<\s]` - 1 символ, отличный от `<` и пробельного символа
- `\K`  - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из текущего совпадения
- `[^<\s]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `<` и пробельного символа

Шаблон замены:

- `\L` - оператор замены символов на строчные
- `$&` - во всем найденном совпадении

Примечание. Опцию *и новые строки* задавать необязательно. *Во всех подпапках* обработает файлы с заданной маской во всех подпапках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]